# Edit WordPress Function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the bottom link to be a button.

How can I incorporate the input type=submit into this function?

You can see the output here: http://zanifesto.com/select-your-plan/

```
function select_plan($params = array(), $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'image_url' => '',
    'title' => 'Title',
    'link_name' => '',
    'link_url' => ''
), $params));

$content = do_shortcode($content);
$select_plan = '
    <div class="shortcode_select_plan">

        <h3>'.$title.'</h3>
        <div class="small_sep"></div>
        <p>'.$content.'</p>
        <a href="'.$link_url.'">'.$link_name.'</a>
    </div>
';
return $select_plan;
}
```

Comment: WHAT do you want, tell us more.

Comment: I want the "Select" to look like the button on this page http://zanifesto.com/contact/. I want it to use this css -

Comment: `form input[type=submit] {
 padding:20px 50px;
 font-size:12px;
 color:#fff;
 border:0;
 margin:0;
 background:#000;
 font-weight:900;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 cursor:pointer;
}

form input[type=submit]:hover {
 background:#b39964;
}`

Comment: I imagine something needs to go around  `<a href="'.$link_url.'">'.$link_name.'</a>` but I can't figure out what it should be. Instead I just keep breaking my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a css `class` and put these style rules inside it

```
.btn_link {
    padding: 20px 50px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFF;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #000;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Add this `class` in your main `css` file and use this class in your code like

```
<a class="btn_link" href="'.$link_url.'">'.$link_name.'</a>
```

That's it. A sample using inline Style in `Chrome` inspector tool is given bellow
[image]

Comment: oh, ok. so you can edit functions similar to other php. I was intimidated by all of the $ and other stuff I hadn't worked with before.